# Convert Excel columns to csv data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like each column of an Excel sheet to become a CSV file having just that column as its only line.

[image]

Example, from the attached Excel screenshot my output should be two csv files (because of the 2 columns) with one row each.
That is the first csv variables will be from 1-9, while the second will be from 11-19.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55379075/5514747

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export each individual excel row to its own individual csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379075/how-to-export-each-individual-excel-row-to-its-own-individual-csv-file)

Comment: before posting my question, i had earlier executed the referenced code. it does except for the fact that it had on header all through, that i was able to resolve. the code takes in values from row to column. what i want is the entire row (variables in a single row).. for the conversion, trust me it did the job..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export Column To Row

- Exports each column of a range to one-row `.csv`-file.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportColumnsToCSV()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\66730122\"
    Const FileLeft As String = "File "
    Const csvDelimiter As String = "," ' or maybe ";"
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)

    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rCount)
    Dim cNum As Long: cNum = FreeFile
    Dim cFile As String
    Dim c As Long, r As Long
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Result(r) = Data(r, c)
        Next r
        cFile = FolderPath & FileLeft & c & ".csv"
        Open cFile For Output As #cNum
        Print #cNum, Join(Result, csvDelimiter)
        Close #cNum
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is more like it, just that I need the all the output in a row and not the way spread them across columns (like vertically arranged)

Comment: You gotta be more specific, I don't understand what you're saying. Maybe try with a practical example e.g. *in the range "A1:B9" I want to write the values "A1:A9" to one file 1,2,3,4... and the values ...*. Maybe use `vbLf` as the `Delimiter`: `Const csvDelimiter As String = vbLf`

Comment: Yeah like  A1:A9 should remain as A1:A9 in the new CSV file, B1: B9 should remain as B1: B9 in the second CSV file and so on

Comment: Like so far the output is good just that the values A1: A9 in the original file when converted to CSV file the arrangement is altered, splitjnf the A1:A9 values into A1:I1...

Comment: `B1:B9` doesn't become `A1:A9` but stays `B1:B9`? Are you sure? This would mean that the values in the 2nd `csv`-file are `,11`  `,12`  `,13`... one below the other. Please do confirm.

Comment: B1: B9 becomes A1: I1, same way A1:A9 becomes A1:I1.. I need A1:A9 to remain as A1:A9 in the new file, B1:B9 to be A1:A9 in the second file and so on.. Its giving me a horizontal result instead of a vertical output..

Comment: In one of my previous comments, I mentioned that you should try `vbLf`. Please do so: `Const csvDelimiter As String = vbLf`.

Comment: Thank you so so much...I'm grateful... Just one last thing, the folder where my excel file is, is on the desktop but the the CSV outputs display on my desktop instead of the same folder, even when I specified it in the Const  Folderpath As String

Comment: Instead of Const... use `Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath  = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I sincerely appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky, I just spent my week on a similar problem. I adapted it to your problem.

Enjoy!

```vb
   Private Sub SplitColumnsInCSV()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TableToSplit As ListObject
    Dim WorkbookPath As String
    Dim CSVLocation As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim i, j, TableColumnCount As Integer
    Dim TempRangeToSplit As Range
   
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Real name of your worksheet where your table is located
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    'Real name of your table in your worksheet
    Set TableToSplit = ws.ListObjects("TableToSplit")

    For i = 1 To TableToSplit.ListColumns.Count
        'adjust temp range for each columns
        Set TempRangeToSplit = TableToSplit.ListColumns(i).Range
        
        'Create à folder with your CSV  where your workbook is located
        CSVLocation = wb.Path & "\CSV\"
        Folder = Dir(CSVLocation, vbDirectory)
        If Folder = "" Then MkDir CSVLocation
    
        'name the csv file
        FilePath = wb.Path & "\CSV\" & ws.Name & TempRangeToSplit.Cells(1, 1).Value & ".csv"
        
        'this piece of code have 2 loops in case of 2 dimentionnal range
        Open FilePath For Output As #1
            For j = 1 To TempRangeToSplit.Rows.Count
                For k = 1 To TempRangeToSplit.Columns.Count
                    cellValue = TempRangeToSplit.Cells(j, k).Value
                    If k = TempRangeToSplit.Columns.Count Then
                        Write #1, cellValue
                    Else
                        Write #1, cellValue,
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```

In detail:

- I fill the temp range with the column I want to extract in CSV
- I create a folder in case it doesn't already exist
- I create the csv file and give it a name
- I write in the csv file all the lines of a column

Be careful, if you reuse the macro, the new files with the same name will overwrite the old ones.

Comment: returns an "invalid outside procedure" and highlights "set" wb = ActiveWorkbook

Comment: "invalid outside procedure" appears because you didn't copy paste this piece of code inside a "sub". I've updated my answer to add à sub, you now need to specify the worksheet name were your table is located

Comment: I scaled though that set wb = ActiveWorkbook stage but got stuck where I had to input the table name

Comment: Do you know what a "table" is for excel? You need to select all your data and "insert">"table". Then the 1st row of every column will have a new filter option. This means that your data are in a table. You have to give a name to this table in the "Design" tab in the "table name" field on the top left. You need to have the same name in the excel sheet as in the vba code.

Comment: I've upload my workbook on wetransfert, https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ca3f8705be76ac9a25c7f76888da2e3820210321223408/39898d You can see everything on it, it works perfectly